# iMessage freeze and crash

Tags: ios, messages, ipod-touch, performance

I am having this problem where I open up iMessage on my iPod Touch 4th Gen iOS 6.0.1 and it freezes after 3 seconds. There is a specific message that is causing this. This app opens up at this conversation by default. Before the three seconds passes, I can press back to the list of conversations and do stuff on that screen normally. But when I try to delete that specific conversation it reppears! I have tried to sign out and sign back in but the problem still remains. I have tried every possible method I could think of. If anybody knows how I can delete this conversation or fix this problem I would be grateful.

Comment: Can anybody please help me with my question?

Answer (score 1):

After many attempts trying to fix this glitch I have finally found the answer.
I will explain step by step.

1. Open up iMessage
2. Quickly go back to the list of conversations before iMessage freezes
3. Go into the conversation that causes the crash
4. Click edit
5. Clear all messages
6. Go back before iMessage freezes
7. Delete the conversation
8. Completely close iMessage by opening up the Multitask bar and hold onto the icon until the icon jiggles.
9. Tap on the delete button on the top left of the icon
10. Wait 10 seconds then open iMessage again

**After these 10 steps iMessage should be working find now.**